# Unity3D: Having player light torches using ParticleSystem and OnCollisionEnter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get my player to light torches in a scene, but not quite sure how to do this.

I have a torch prefab that has a particle system. Each time the player's torch collides into an unlit torch, I would like that torch to start burning.

I have been trying to follow the docs but have not been able to understand  (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Play.html).

Also have this question posted here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1491419/having-player-light-torches-using-particle-system.html

My current code is below. I have each torch object tagged as torch, and my player tagged as Player. All particle systems, except the player's torch, have 'Play on Awake' off and prewarm on.

Any advice or tips?

Thanks!

```
/* 
 * Attach this script to all the torches. It will be used to start the fire 
   using OnCollision?/OnTrigger? See which is better
 * Start with the particle effect/light being off, get all the components
 * Turn the torches on when the player's torch collides with them
 * 1.) Must make sure each torch object has a collider
 * */

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StartFire : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject torch;
    public ParticleSystem fireParticleSystem;
    bool lightOn;

    void Start()
    {
        lightOn = false; //Start with the light off
        fireParticleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>(); //get Particle System 
        torch = GetComponent<GameObject>(); //get Torch
    }

   /*
    * if player's torch hits this torch (that is not lit)
    * Turn on the fire
    * Set the light being on to true
    * */
   private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) 
   {
        if(this.gameObject.tag==("torch") && collision.gameObject.tag==("Player") && lightOn==false)
        {
           fireParticleSystem.Play(); //start the particle system
           lightOn = true;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**.Create your `ParticleSystem` and change the tag of its GameObject to "torch".

**2**.Attach BoxCollider to the SphereCollider to that GameObject with the ParticleSystem.

**3**.Mark the `IsTrigger` of the collider created from **#2** to be true because it doen't make sense to collide with a touch. It seems like you just want to detect when the player is touching it.

**4**.The touch script should attached to the player instead of the touch. Use `OnTriggerEnter` to handle the detection and detect when player touches the touch-light then use `GetComponent` to get the `ParticleSystem` and play it. Stop the particle in `OnTriggerExit`.

If you actually want player to collide and be stopped by the touch then ignore **#2** and also use `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit` instead of `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit`.

Attach to the Player:

```
public class ParticlePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        //Make sure player is touching a touch
        if (other.CompareTag("torch"))
        {
            //Get ParticleSystem from the Gameobject the player collided with
            ParticleSystem ps = other.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

            //Play Particle
            ps.Play();
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        //Make sure player is touching a touch
        if (other.CompareTag("torch"))
        {
            //Get ParticleSystem from the Gameobject the player collided with
            ParticleSystem ps = other.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

            //Stop Particle
            ps.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked thank you @Programmer! I will be putting it into VR so the player will be stopping/starting on their own will. I will do some more looking into Trigger versus Collision to see which is best.  @Daniel I think I may need the emission starting for my 'initial' torch lighting, will try that out :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following code in some of my projects:

```
private ParticleSystem _particleSystem;
private ParticleSystem.EmissionModule _emissionModule;

private void Awake()
{
    _particleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    _emissionModule = _particleSystem.emission;

    _emissionModule.enabled = false;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) 
{
    _emissionModule.enabled = true;
    _particleSystem.Play();
}
```

I believe you're missing the emission module.